Pls Help! AR(1) Covariance derivation query

Can someone pls explain to me why they can do this when deriving the autocovariance of AR(1)
Why can they just add a $\phi$ in front of μ ? Shouldn't it be: $\phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t - \mu$
Much appreciated.

Hi: It depends how the AR(1) is defined. Sometimes it defined as
as (1) $$y_{t} - \mu = \phi (y_t - \mu) + \epsilon_t$$
Other times its defined  as
(2) $$y_{t} = \phi y_t  + \mu + \epsilon_t$$
So, in the first one, the overall mean of the process is "zero" ( after normalization by subtracting it from $y_t$ everywhere ) and, in the second one, it is not. Clearly, the author must be using the first definition. I find the first definition not as intuitive. Clearly, they are not the same model but if you add $\mu$ to both sides of (1), you obtain
$$y_t = \phi y_t + (1-\phi) \mu + \epsilon_t$$
So, (1) can be thought of as (2) with the mean of the process being $(1-\phi) \mu$. Therefore, it really doesn't matter whether one uses
version (1) or version (2).

Thank u so much! That makes a lot of sense. May I ask under what situations will the first expression be used more commonly in practice? What's the advantage of the first expression, compared to $\mu + \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ in real life?

Hi Alex: There's really no difference in the two models. The only difference is that if you use the formulation described in (1), then you need to remember that the true mean of the process is $(1-\phi) \mu$ and not $\mu$. Other than that, there's no difference.

and you're welcome. I'm glad that it seems to have helped.

Wait sorry. Aren't the true means (expected values) of both y_t equal to ? Did you mean they have different drifts, one is (1−) and the other is just ?

Hi: I'm not sure what you mean ( no pun intended ) by the term "drift" ? I know its used for sure but  I don't use it . I think of the constant term as the long term mean when the model is in equlibrium. By that, I mean what the level of the series is when the shocks have died out and things have settled down and there are no shocks.  Notice that,  in the two models, by my definition, the long term equilibrium values are not the same. One is $\mu$ and the other is $(1-\phi \mu)$.

But if you estimate both models on the same set of data, then $\hat{\mu}$ in model (2) will be equal to $(1- \hat{\phi}) \hat \mu$ in model (1). This is what I mean when I say that it really doesn't matter which one you use.

The last line of the second to last comment should read "One is $\mu$ and the other is $(1-\phi)\mu$." My mistake.
